# How to disable Facebook login in React Native Auth0?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I used React-Native-Lock.

But I don't want to log in using facebook.

How can I disable it?

Comment: Any codes? Errors? Anything you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it where.

I guess where is react-native-lock pod project.

I found #define FACEBOOK_ENABLED there.

But I don't know how to disable it.

...
lock.show(...);

Comment: That's default Auth0 Log in UI.
I have any errors, just want to disable fackbook log in and icon.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you will have to do it manually from your Auth0 dashboard.
Just go and turn of facebook login from Auth0 account. Will automatically disable when you run your app.

Comment: Please provide proper source code, documentation and add more details about your answer